# how to store java list in realm android database

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

How we can store java list in realm android database. I try to store it by using setter method present in my model, but it doesn't work and I get "Each element of 'value' must be a valid managed object" in exception message.

```
public void storeNewsList(String categoryId, List<News> newsList) { 
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance(); 
    realm.beginTransaction(); 
    NewsList newsListObj = realm.createObject(NewsList.class); 
    newsListObj.setNewsList(new RealmList<>(newsList.toArray(new News[newsList.size()]))); 
    newsListObj.setCategoryId(categoryId); 
    realm.commitTransaction(); 
    realm.close(); 
}
```

Comment: Share your code what you have done?

Comment: public void storeNewsList(String categoryId, List<News> newsList) {
    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
    realm.beginTransaction();
    NewsList newsListObj = realm.createObject(NewsList.class);
    

    newsListObj.setNewsList(newsListObj.setNewsList(new RealmList<>(newsList.toArray(new News[newsList.size()]))););
    newsListObj.setCategoryId(categoryId);
    realm.commitTransaction();
    realm.close();
}

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Replace code with

```
public void storeNewsList(String categoryId, List<News> newsList) { 
    try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) { 
        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
             @Override
             public void execute(Realm realm) {
                 NewsList newsListObj = new NewsList(); // <-- create unmanaged
                 RealmList<News> _newsList = new RealmList<>();
                 _newsList.addAll(newsList);
                 newsListObj.setNewsList(_newsList); 
                 newsListObj.setCategoryId(categoryId);
                 realm.insert(newsListObj); // <-- insert unmanaged to Realm
             }
        }); 
    }
}
```

Comment: newsListObj.setNewsList(new RealmList<>(newsList));  getting error unable to resolve constructor.

Comment: ah, well then `addAll()` it is

Comment: It work for me with just one correction instead of RealmList<NewsList> _newsList = new RealmList<>(); I need to add RealmList<News> _newsList = new RealmList<>();

Comment: Do we need to close the realm? Does your solution create a memory leak ?

Comment: Of course, try with resources autocloses Realm instance

Comment: @EpicPandaForce you're awesome. \m/

Comment: @EpicPandaForce one quick question.can we use `Realm.getDefaultInstance().copyFromRealm(Realm.getDefaultInstance().where(HomeJob.class).findAll()` from multiple threads. Just to avoid error.

Comment: @Aks4125 god no you're leaking 2 realm instances per a single line O_o

Answer (score 1):

In case if you're using @PrimaryKey then `insertOrUpdate` will do the trick

```
try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
                        realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                            @Override
                            public void execute(Realm realm) {
                                 RealmList<News> _newsList = new RealmList<>();
                                _newsList.addAll(myCustomArrayList);
                                realm.insertOrUpdate(_newsList); // <-- insert unmanaged to Realm

                            }
                        });
                    }
```